# gmap v3 clear specific marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3

to clear markers from google maps I use:

```
mapContent.gmap('clear', 'markers');
```

But what if I want to clear specific markers, not all, lets say by their IDs? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you clear a marker from the map is by calling the setMap(null) on the [marker](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker). It looks like you are using some third party plugin ([jquery-ui-map](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) perhaps?) for google maps. If you are using jquery-ui-map, use the `find` method to find the marker you want, then call `setMap(null)` on it.

Answer (score 0):

marker.setMap(null) will only clear the marker overlay.  It will not destroy the marker. As "clear" is potentially for.  I too want to clear the markers and destroy the one I clicked. I have a working demo which I am willing to share.  Though I used marker.setMap(null) it only hides the marker.  I have yet to find a way to completely destroy it.

jsFiddle:

[jsfiddle.net/ryanverdel/WRyrJ/](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanverdel/WRyrJ/)

Code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

      var markerCount = 0;

      $("#test1").gmap3({
          map: {
              options: {
                  center: [-2.2214281090541204, -78.695068359375],
                  zoom: 8,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                  mapTypeControl: true,
                  mapTypeControlOptions: {
                      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
                  },
                  navigationControl: true,
                  scrollwheel: true,
                  disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                  streetViewControl: false,

              },
              events: {


                  click: function (map, event) {

                      if (markerCount < 10) {


                          $(this).gmap3(

                          {
                              marker: {
                                  latLng: event.latLng,
                                  options: {
                                      draggable: true,
                                      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                                  },



                                  events: {
                                      click: function (marker) {

                                          marker.setMap(map);
                                          marker.setMap(null);
                                          marker = null;
                                          delete marker;
                                          console.log(marker);

                                          markerCount--;
                                      },

                                      dragend: function (marker) {
                                          $("#inputArray").empty();

                                          setTimeout(function () {
                                              var markers = $("#test1").gmap3({
                                                  get: {
                                                      all: true
                                                  }
                                              });

                                              $.each(markers, function (i, marker) {

                                                  $("#inputArray").append('<p>{"latitude":' + marker.position.lat() + ', ' + '"longitude":' + marker.position.lng() + '},' + '</p>');
                                              });
                                          }, 400);



                                      }


                                  },


                              },


                          });

                          markerCount++;

                          $("#inputArray").empty();

                          setTimeout(function () {
                              var markers = $("#test1").gmap3({
                                  get: {
                                      all: true
                                  }
                              });

                              $.each(markers, function (i, marker) {

                                  $("#inputArray").append('<p>{"latitude":' + marker.position.lat() + ', ' + '"longitude":' + marker.position.lng() + '},' + '</p>');
                              });
                          }, 400);

                      } else {
                          return false;
                      };

                  }
              }
          }
      });

  });
```